# Is there any API available for AWS Pricing Calculator

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any API available for https://calculator.aws/#/  ?

Comment: I doubt it. It basically a frontend only application, there is no complicated backend in place, if you open the browser console you can see a bunch of static json files being accessed, they contain all the relevant information do display input fields a and calculate the cost.

Comment: not able to find any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no API for the AWS Pricing Calculator.

There is an [AWS Price List API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html) that can provide pricing for individual resources, but you would then need to multiply the individual costs based upon intended usage (eg 12 hours @ $0.10 per hour).

Comment: AWS Pricing Calculator provides only a console interface at https://calculator.aws/#/. It doesn't provide an API. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pricing-calculator/latest/userguide/what-is-pricing-calculator.html#accessing-apc

Comment: But we could reverse engineer the JSON data used in calculator.aws to build our own local API to calculate the pricing, like https://calculator.aws/pricing/2.0/meteredUnitMaps/computesavingsplan/USD/current/compute-instance-savings-plan-ec2-calc/t3.small/EU%20(Paris)/Linux/NA/Shared/index.json

The idea is to use the F12 while querying our data in console to get the JSON data URL.